# Is it correct to say "mission completed"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

Is it correct to say  "mission is completed" or I should say  "mission completed"?

Comment: How is this being used?

Comment: If you're looking for the usual catchphrase, it's _mission accomplished_.

Comment: Context needed.

Comment: Not if you haven’t completed the mission.